# how to load Arcgis map via proxy.ashx in iOS application?

Tags: ios, dictionary, proxy, arcgis

I am working on iOS app that uses AGSRuntime Environment API for iOS to load a map layers (dynamic and features layers) via a .Net proxy called "proxy.ashx" . As in the following code lines:

```
NSString *MAPServiceURL = @"https://myDomain/sourceCodePath/proxy.ashx?http://my_ArcGis_Server/arcgis/rest/services/MapService/MapServer/"
NSString *FeatureLayerURL = @"https://myDomain/sourceCodePath/proxy.ashx?http://my_ArcGis_Server/arcgis/rest/services/MapService/MapServer/0"
self.dynamicLayer = [AGSDynamicMapServiceLayer dynamicMapServiceLayerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MAPServiceURL]];

self.featureLayer = [[AGSFeatureLayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FeatureLayerURL] mode:AGSFeatureLayerModeSnapshot];
```

My Problem is that the dynamic layer does not appear. and no error happens on the iOS app side.

On the proxy.ashx side it redirects the request and returns the response (OK 200) as HTML Page.

Note: the same map loaded successfully in a web application uses AGSRuntime Environment API for JavaScript via the same "proxy.ashx".

So, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when app request in POST the `NSURLConnection` will remove the unwanted parameter from URL (everything after the `?` because it is GET parameter). So you can try to set the map service URL without the proxy URL.

```
NSString *mapServiceURL = @"http://my_ArcGis_Server/arcgis/rest/services/MapService/MapServer/";
```

Or you can use [ArcGIS Web Adaptor](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/about-the-arcgis-web-adaptor.htm) for public access to your intranet ArcGIS server, if you don't want to set your ArcGIS server as public domain.

Comment: When loading the dynamic layer (by using dynamicMapServiceLayerWithURL message) I do not identify the request type (GET or POST) and I did not find any method (in AGSRuntime Environment API for iOS) allows me to change it.

Comment: Can you try to request directly by removing the proxy URL?

Comment: Yes, the map loads and every thing goes well when I connect to my internal network because my_ArcGis_Server is an internal server has no public IP, so I am trying to use the proxy to let me access the internal network of myDomain when I connect to the internet.

Comment: if there is another approach (differs from using the proxy.ashx) to access my_ArcGis_Server in internal network from the internet, I would like to know about

Comment: I think you should use ArcGIS Web Adaptor for public access to your intranet ArcGIS server, if you don't want to set your ArcGIS server as public domain. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/about-the-arcgis-web-adaptor.htm

Comment: Thank you.. the ArcGIS Web Adaptor idea worked for me